# Common practices to avoid timeouts / starvation in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, queue

I have a web-service that write files to disk and other stuff to database. The entire operation takes 1-2 seconds for each write.

The service can, bur that is unlikely, be called from several clients at the same time. Let´s assume that 20 clients call the webservice at the same time, the write operations must be synchronized. In that case, some clients can get a time out exception because they have to wait to many seconds.

Are there any good practices to solve these kind of situations? As it is now, the methods are synchronized (and that can cause the starvation/timeouts).

Should I let all threads get into the write method by removing the `synchronized` keyword and put their task into a task queue to avoid a timeout? Is that the correct way to get arount this?

Comment: It sounds like the client is broken. If the service can normally take several seconds but the clients timeout, then the clients are timing out too soon. Or if the clients are supposed to time out soon, then timeouts are normal, and clients must deal with them elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `synchronized` and putting it into a task queue by itself will not help you (because that's effectively what the synchronized is doing for you). However if you respond to the web request as soon as you put it on the queue, then you will reduce your response fime. But at the cost of some reliability as the user will get a confirmation that the work is done and the work will not really have been done (the system could crash before the work is done).

Answer (score 1):

Francis Upton's practice is indeed an accepted practice.

Another one, is making more fine grained synchronization. Instead of synchronizing all read/write methods of a class, you can synchronize access of the exact invariants that should be synchronized.

And yet even better, is to get rid of synchronization altogether. This is possible using the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. This package introduce new collections that use [Non-Blocking Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) (implemented in java using [Compare-Ans-Swap](http://Compare-and-swap) atomic instructions). These collections, such as [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), enable much better throughput when scaling.

You can read more about it in [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11234/).

Answer (score 1):

In this type of implementation (slow service under increasing load) you want to make as much as possible async, including the timeout processing (if server-based) and the required I/O.  Don't hold up your client response threads waiting for either of these time-consuming operations, to preserve the server's responsiveness to new requests, but instead fire off the required operations (maybe to a dynamic thread pool) and let callbacks process the results, whether timeout, complete I/O, or errors.

Send the appropriate response depending on what happens first, but be prepared to roll back I/O if you send an error/timeout message and then a completed I/O arrives (due to a race condition between I/O and timer).  This implies transactional semantics are required in the server.

This is an area that get increasingly complex as your load grows but good design early on should allow you to scale as load grows.  Ideally the client servicing threads should not block at all.